# I'm not able to setup Android Data Binding

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have this in my root `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
}
```

and in the app `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.app"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    //more third-party libraries
}
```

And this is my layout:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="user"
            type="com.company.app.models.LoginCredentials"/>
    </data>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:text="@{user.username}"/>

    <!-- More layouts and widgets -->
</layout>
```

But I get this error:

> Error:(82, 35) No resource type specified (at 'text' with value
>   '@{user.username}').

I have tried to put:

```
dataBinding { 
    enabled = true 
}
```

but I get this another error:

> Error:Could not find com.android.databinding:library:1.0-rc3.

How can I do? I have just updated Android Studio to v1.5.1.

Comment: At first set `compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1" &  targetSdkVersion 23` & `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'`

Comment: as @IntelliJAmiya says change version 21 to 23

Comment: And don't forget `dataBinding{ enabled = true }`in the  `android  { }`  section.

Comment: At least it works!! Thanks! I have put `dataBinding.enabled = true` and updated version to 23

Comment: @bigdestroyer Glad to hear .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually **`compileSdkVersion 21`** creating problem . You need to use **UPGRADED** Version .

You should use

```
compileSdkVersion 23 
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
```

&

```
targetSdkVersion 23
```

You need to include **`dataBinding.enabled = true`**

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `classpath "com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc1"` to your build.gradle like this

   `buildscript {
       repositories {
           jcenter()
       }
       dependencies {
           classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
           classpath "com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc1"
       }
   }`
2. Change your build.gradle on putting what as mentioned in the previous comments of @IntelliJAmiya and adding `apply plugin: 'com.android.databinding'` Your gradle will be like

   ```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
   apply plugin: 'com.android.databinding'  
    android {
       compileSdkVersion 23
       buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"


     defaultConfig {
           applicationId "com.company.app"
           minSdkVersion 14
           targetSdkVersion 21
           versionCode 1
           versionName "1.0"
       }
       buildTypes {
           release {
               minifyEnabled false
               proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),   'proguard-rules.pro'
           }
       }
   }
    dataBinding { 
           enabled = true 
       }
       dependencies {
           compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
           testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
           compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
           //more third-party libraries
       }
   `
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, `com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc1` is not needed to be declared explicitly. It is included in `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'`.